# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} for all

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, http-status-code-301

We used to have a url pattern that was something like `www.website.com/wmspage.cfm?parm1=1000` with 1000 being the page ID.

I did a few 301 rewrites like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} parm1=513
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/new-url/? [R=301,L]
```

BUT now I want to actually take all of these old parm1=id strings to 301 them to our homepage rather than doing these redirects on an individual basis. How do I make this a universal redirect?

Is there way to capture all urls with parm1=whatever?

Comment: Simple: change `parm1=513` to `parm1=\d+`, where `\d+` is an expression for 'one or more digits'.

Comment: PERFECT! I knew there was a quick and easy way but I couldn't remember.

Comment: Going to add this as an answer to help others too. Please accept it once I've done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To catch all IDs for `parm1`, just use the `\d+` expression to catch all digits in your condition:

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} parm1=\d+
```